# Add a date timestamp to an output file displaying the ping results of a hostname

Tags: datetime, dos, command-prompt

I need to view the ping results of a website/hostname continuously. So I am trying to output the results to a text file. I want to add the date and time stamps as the name of the output file. For Eg:

ping google.com -t>  datetimestamp.txt

where datetimestamp=the specific date and time when the ping was done.

Thanks!
Muddu

Answer (score 1):

SET HOUR=%time:~-11,2%
Call :TRIM %HOUR%
GOTO :EOF
:TRIM
Set HOUR=_%*
REM Create our timestamp filename variable
SET DATESTMP=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%HOUR%
SET FILENAME={xxxx}log_%DATESTMP%%time~-8,2%%time:~-5,2%.txt
echo. Pinging {xxxx} >>%FILENAME%
echo. Ping {#1} >>%FILENAME%
Ping {#1 IP Address}>>%FILENAME%

I created this batch file to ping a small number of workstations at different store locations.

{xxxx} represents the actual store #.
{#1} represents the router, host or workstation identification.
{#1 IP Address} represents the corresponding IP Address to match the above identification